# Saving jpg in SQL from Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to save a jpg file into SQL and display it in an Access FE. In SQL I have a table with a varbinary(max) column. In Access a form referencing the field which does not display the image but searching found that if I set something like `Image1.PictureData = me.sqlImage` in the Form_Current() I can get it to display.

Now the issue. If I insert the picture in T-SQL with something like this

```
UPDATE MyTableName

SET SQLImage=(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'test.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as x)

WHERE IndexField='0123'
```

It displays the image as desired. However, if I attempt to insert\update the image from VBA with the following,

```
    Set dlgAdd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With dlgAdd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Picture Files (*.jpg, * .jpeg)", "*.jpg;*.jpeg"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select Picture"

        If .Show = True Then
            '-- Open .Item For Binary As #1
            Open .SelectedItems(1) For Binary As #1
            '-- ReDim bytData(FileLen(.Item))
            ReDim bytData(FileLen(.SelectedItems(1)) -1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Get #1, , bytData
    Close #1


    Set DB = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE IndexField='" & Me.IndexField & "'"
    Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    RS.OpenRecordset

    RS.Edit
    RS.Fields("SQLImage").AppendChunk bytData
    RS.Update
    RS.Close
```

Then I get the lovely "The bitmap you specified is not in a device-independent bitmap (.dib) format" error attempting the `Image1.PictureData` Searching more I found a reference to using a Web Browser Control to convert it to base64 which doesn't give me the error but only displays the small "x" box instead of the image so it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong saving the jpg from Access VBA? It works fine if I insert the image from T-SQL but I want to have the users update the images from the FE.

Thanks in advance,

Edit: Found article https://rtmccormick.com/2013/08/22/select-a-file-with-file-dialog-in-ms-access-with-vba/ and changed from `.Item` to `.SelectedItems(1)`. Left my original use commented for clarity. Based on comments checked size with a test integer and was showing 0 length after Open. Changed to `.SelectedItems(1)` and now behaves correctly. Thanks to @Charles & @Erik A getting me to stop focusing on the tree. :)

Edit2: I've included the test if file selected or canceled out if someone tries to copy\paste since I haven't included everything (dims etc) but that part should have been there.

Comment: is the redim correct? i found an example with : ReDim byteArr(0 To LOF(fileInt) - 1) which would be FileLen(.Item) -1.  The Error means it wants the image in .DIB format, which is very similar to BMP, so maybe the control can't handle a compressed jpg image? check if the bytes are correct in the database, and compare the bytes before you look for other errors.

Comment: The redim is indeed wrong. Arrays are 0-based by default, so you have a single byte too much in `bytData`, which corrupts the image. Depending on the exact type of JPEG (there are many), it may or may not be supported, but a webbrowser control supports almost all of them (CMYK jpegs are a notable exception).

Comment: @Charles & @Erik A thank you for pointing that out. I was in a rabbit hole thinking it was a format issue since if I copied and pasted to the control it also would not work. Didn't think to check the size. The jpg file is 152324 bytes in size. If I use T-SQL the size is the same. If I paste to the control it ends up being 152681 for some reason. The VBA code only 1 byte. If I try `ReDim bytData(FileLen(.Item) - 1)` then I get a subscript out of range.

Comment: SQL and T-SQL are not databases, they are query languages. Should tag with database used. I am guessing it is SQLServer.